# NavigationView stylized

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-navigationview

I would like to make a menu style nubank application (left menu) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9LSu.png) but to let the icons to show when and drag to the right to appear what each option. I searched and found nothing about it. I know I do with a navigation view and only know how to do the traditional. Does anyone know how should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I found a library which is similar to the image you posted just add

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:(latest-release)@aar'
}
```

in your gradle file and follow the instruction given [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1388).Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you!! 
You helped me a lot!!

Comment: Is the answer fits your requirement ??